# Nagios check_http: -I vs. -H

Tags: nagios

Here's a weird one:

```
root@shrike:~# /omd/sites/mon1/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -4 -I 192.168.6.23 -p 8080 -u /api
CRITICAL - Socket timeout after 10 seconds

root@shrike:~# /omd/sites/mon1/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -4 -H 192.168.6.23 -p 8080 -u /api
HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 495 bytes in 0.174 second response time |time=0.173559s;;;0.000000;10.000000 size=495B;;;0
```

The help says

> -H, --hostname=ADDRESS
>      Host name argument for servers using host headers (virtual  host)
>      Append a port to include it in the header (eg: example.com:5000)
>
> -I, --IP-address=ADDRESS
>      IP address or name (use numeric address if possible to bypass DNS lookup).

So here -H works and -I doesn't.  There's no virtual host being used here - it's a node/express based service.

Comment: You can throw a -v (or -vv, -vvv) on the end to see the exact headers being sent/received. I'm not sure what your question is, here. One way sends a Host: header, the other doesn't. Whether or not that works is up to your application.

Answer (score 1):

In short:

- `-I` specifies the address to connect via HTTP
- `-H` specifies the Host header for the HTTP/1.1 protocol (aka the vhost)

When `-I` is not set, `-H` is used to connect with.